# Speech-to-Text Uppercase Letter Problem

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, voice-recognition

Whenever I compose any type of message through speech-to-text, a problem occurs which is rather annoying and seemingly, there is no workaround.

The problem:

Android capitalises the first letter of the sentence, which is great.  But it then proceeds to capitalise every occurrence of the same letter wherever it appears throughout the rest of the sentence.  For example:

```
This senTence is an example senTence ThaT has been composed Through speech-To-TexT.
```

I have turned auto-capitalisation off and this (obviously) results in no capital letters being used either at the beginning of the sentence, nor are any occurrences of the letter `I` capitalised.  This is almost as annoying as the main problem.

I would like to know if anybody has had a similar problem and, if so, is there a solution to this problem?

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note and am running Android 2.3.6 (Gingerbread).

Many thanks.

Comment: Is it the same for all apps or just certain ones?

Comment: All apps - please see my answer; it explains the solution.

Comment: Interesting Problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a solution for this problem.

The only apparent way around it is to change the keyboard from the default keyboard to the [Swype](http://www.swype.com/get-swype/how-do-i-get-swype/) keyboard.

Click [here](http://www.swype.com/) if you would like to know what Swype is; at first I was a little dubious, but it really is quite marvellous and accurate!

Why this resolves the problem, I do not know, but I am just happy that it does and am certain that this will provide some respite to those of you who are also experiencing this annoying problem.

Comment: it probably solves your problem because Swype uses Dragon Dictation (to my knowledge) to handle their speech-to-text instead of Google's, which sounds like what you were having the problem with.